# How can I capture data from TimePicker?

Tags: c#, javascript

I am a beginner and I want to capture the time is selected from a TimePicker to display it in another page, how I can do?

this is the html code of TimePicker

```
<ew:TimePicker runat="server" ID="tpInicio" Width="90px" Scrollable="True" Nullable="False" NumberOfColumns="2" MinuteInterval="30" PopupWidth="140px" PopupHeight="175px" CssClass="captura" BackColor="White">
   <TimeStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke" ForeColor="Black" />
   <SelectedTimeStyle BackColor="DarkGray" ForeColor="White" />
   <ClearTimeStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" ForeColor="Black" />
</ew:TimePicker>
```

Thanks

Comment: `<ew:` which library is this? You may try to see the documentation about that. server side code might be `tpInicio.Value` or `tpInicio.SelectedDate` please see the intellisense... Is it using a jquery-ui datepicker?

Comment: Have tried documentation at http://www.eworldui.net/? and to pass information between pages read on ASP.NET things like "session" or "querystring"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using exCentrics.net? If so you can try `tpInicio.SelectedTime`.

I suggest you also check [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) for some better alternative.